# Need tax to be included from my product checkout Magento2

Tags: magento2, tax, tax-class, tax-calculation, taxes

I added a simple product including tax $9.99 as the price looks nice and rounded for an attractive market.

As European countries like UK doesn’t vary by state and not like US(for US tax varies depending on the state and zip code) – it’s the same in all states or countries, and catalog prices are displayed with taxes and so we are entering products with taxes already calculated in the product price

Right now my system on settings

> Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Tax >> Calculation Settings >>
>   **Catalog Prices = Including Tax**
>
> Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Tax >> Default Tax Destination Calculation >>
>   **Default Country = United Kingdom & Default State = ***

Also setup **Tax Rules and Tax Zones & Rates** to 20% with settings as UK with * for Country & zipCode and with a taxable class to product and customer.

**My output**

[image]

**Expected output**

[image]

Is it possible on Magento, How to configure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I got this fixed, I was missing Origin settings.

Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Tax  do the following configuration.
[image]

Store >> Configuration >> Sales >> Shipping Settings do the following configuration (I was missing this setting).

[image]